# Codeigniter URI Segment Not Working properly online

Tags: codeigniter

Please have a look at the following url:-

> English: http://www.santinepal.com/demo/en
>
> Nepali: http://www.santinepal.com/demo/np

The codeigniter profiler is ON but it shows

URI STRING
No URI data exists

The `$this->uri->segment(1);` shouldve returned en or np but it reruns nothing.

This works fine on my localhost.

my **routes.php** file has:-

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'front';
$route['backend'] = 'backend/sentry';

// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|np)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en' and '/fr' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|np)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your .htaccess file is the same on the server and that URL Rewriting is enabled.

Navigating to http://www.santinepal.com/demo/index.php/en shows the URI segments working, so it must be server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar, turns out some server setup caused the issue. Try changing your .htaccess file that removes the index.php to this:

```
#CODE IGNITER - REMOVE INDEX.PHP
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|file_uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The last line is the only one that is different, there is a ? after the index.php.